# WordPress redirect URL

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website [www.artlogdigi.com](http://www.artlogdigi.com/) workes fine, however we found that some people have visited [www.artlogdigi.com/index.html](http://www.artlogdigi.com/index.html) which page is obviously doesn't exist and shows 404 error page.

We also found people visited [contact/index.html](http://www.artlogdigi.com/contact/index.html), [about-us/index.html](http://www.artlogdigi.com/about-us/index.html) which shows 404 too.

I wonder is my server or WordPress redirecting visitors to that kind of URL?

BTW! We are using GoDaddy hosting for our website and installed WordPress using GoDaddy easy install service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a redirect rule to remove `/index.htmml` from any URI.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Make sure this is **first rule in your root .htaccess**

Comment: thanks for your reply, it seems making sense. I will test it and let you know. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could install the redirections plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

This will allow you to track all 404s and create 301 redirects for each without having to edit  the .htaccess file.